# Change image source in Windows 8

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-8, windows-8.1

In XAML I have an image: `<Image x:Name="Tlo" Margin="0,0,10,11" Source="Images/detail_bg.png" Stretch="Fill"/>`
I'd like to change image to another after taping on one button. Inside body of function which handles this event there is a code to change image:

```
 Tlo.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/detail_bgp.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

When I was running an application I had been getting exception: 
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Podana klasy System.Uri nie można przekształcić na klasę Windows.Foundation.Uri. Aby uzyskać więcej informacji, zobacz http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=215849.
Then part in Polish of additional information means something like: Class System.Uri can't be process into class Windows.Fundation.Uri

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is use an absolute URI, as the link suggests:

```
Tlo.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/detail_bgp.png", UriKind.Absolute));
```

If that doesn't work replace `ms-appx` with `ms-appx-web`.